# how to light up Led light using Vb USB

Tags: vb.net, usb, led

hello guys I have a project that will need to turn ON and OFF the LED lights using vb. I have already done it through Parallel port but I realize that parallel port is already out on market, I need to do it using USB. How is that?
should I use USB A to B? USB to serial(db9)? USB to parallel? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a while back and came to the conclusion that you need to buy hardware to do it through USB.  The hardware costs between $50 and $150 depending on how many lines you want to flip and whether you build it as a kit or buy it already working.

Comment: ...and the search term for appropriate hardware would be "usb i/o card".

Comment: try "USB relay controllers"